# Поставить балун для каждого маршрута и отцентрировать карту относительно нескольких маршрутов яндекс карты(API 2.1)

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть карта, с несколькими маршрутами, как поставить балун для каждого маршрута, чтоб по нажатию на маршрут он открывался, и как отцентрировать карту относительно всех маршрутов??

```js
var myMap, ymaps;
// Инициализировать карту
function init() {
  var winWidth  = $(window).width(),
    myMap   = document.getElementById("map");
  $('#map .loader').fadeOut('600');
  if (!myMap) return;

  myMap = new ymaps.Map(myMap, {
    center: [53.451296, 26.473253],
    zoom: 17,
    controls: []
  });

  myMap.controls.add("zoomControl", {});
  if(winWidth <= 1024){
    myMap.behaviors.disable('drag');
  }

  var data = {
    'routs':[
      [
        {
          "infoPoint": '<a class="link-map" href="#">Ссылка на место</a>',
          "coords": [53.903311, 27.560460],
          "colorRouts": '#c51216'
        },
        {
          "infoPoint": '<a class="link-map" href="#">Ссылка на место</a>',
          "coords": [53.684175, 27.130098],
          "colorRouts": '#c51216'
        },
        {
          "infoPoint": '<a class="link-map" href="#">Ссылка на место</a>',
          "coords": [53.483093, 26.740127],
          "colorRouts": '#c51216'
        },
        {
          "infoPoint": '<a class="link-map" href="#">Ссылка на место</a>',
          "coords": [53.451614, 26.474540],
          "colorRouts": '#c51216'
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "infoPoint": '<a class="link-map" href="#">Ссылка на место</a>',
          "coords": [53.675951, 23.828641],
          "colorRouts": '#2ecc71'
        },
        {
          "infoPoint": '<a class="link-map" href="#">Ссылка на место</a>',
          "coords": [53.451092, 26.474309],
          "colorRouts": '#2ecc71'
        }
      ]
    ]
  };

  var routsList = [];
  var myBaloon;

  data.routs.forEach(function(item, index){
    var colorRouts;
    item.forEach(function(item){
      routsList.push(item.coords);
      myBaloon = item.infoPoint;
      colorRouts = item.colorRouts;
    });
    createRoute(routsList, colorRouts, myBaloon, index);
    routsList = [];
  });


  function createRoute(coords, colorRouts, myBaloon, index) {
    var multiRoute = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute(
      {
        referencePoints: coords,
        params: {
          results: 1
        }
      },
      {
        // Внешний вид маршрута
        pinIconFillColor: colorRouts,
        pinActiveIconFillColor: colorRouts,

        routeStrokeWidth: 5,
        routeStrokeColor: colorRouts,
        routeActiveStrokeWidth: 5,
        routeActiveStrokeColor: colorRouts,

        wayPointVisible: false,
        wayPointStartVisible: true,
        wayPointFinishVisible: true,

        // Автоматически устанавливать границы карты так, чтобы маршрут был виден целиком.
        boundsAutoApply: true,
        zoomMargin: 20
      }
    );

    myMap.geoObjects.add(multiRoute);
    data.routs[index].forEach(function(item, index){
      myBaloon = ymaps.templateLayoutFactory.createClass(item.infoPoint);
      multiRoute.model.events.once("requestsuccess", function () {
        var yandexWayPoint = multiRoute.getWayPoints().get(index);
        ymaps.geoObject.addon.balloon.get(yandexWayPoint);
        yandexWayPoint.options.set({
          balloonContentLayout: myBaloon
        });
      });
    });
  }

  //myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds(), {checkZoomRange: true, zoomMargin:42});

}

$(document).ready(function(){
  if (ymaps != undefined) ymaps.ready(init);
});
```

```css
#map{
height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Через `myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds(), {checkZoomRange: true, zoomMargin:42});` отцентрировать не вышло, Кто знает напишите плиз.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) [Для каждого маршрута можно создать свой балун](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_custom_balloon_layout)

2) Таким способом можно отцентрировать, необходимо только дождаться готовности маршрута, чтобы он построился и выдал правильный bounds.

```
myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds(), {checkZoomRange: true, zoomMargin:42});
```

Можешь попробовать отследить по событию *update*.
Вот здесь рабочий пример твой: https://jsfiddle.net/Lrhzy1oL/1/

Comment: Интересное решение, спасибо! Единственное что мне бы не хотелось писать свой балун, а хочу чтоб был стандартный но внутрь поставить свой текст, balloonContentLayout если писать, то он не ставит именно для полосы маршрута

Comment: Стандартный балун маршрута менять нельзя